# Any data about Trump supporters amount in National Guard?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, military, joe-biden, inauguration

As we [know](https://abcnews.go.com/Politics/inside-25000-national-guardsmen-arriving-washington-dc/story?id=75299202), now there is about 25000 national guardsmen in Washington DC. But doesn't it increase risk of strikes from the inside, from hidden Trump supporters? More people - seems more risky. And FBI is now [checking](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2021-01-18/joe-biden-inaugration-fbi-vets-national-guard-insider-attack/13067114) that forces.

Is there any data about Trump supporters amount in National Guard?

Comment: Impressing.) Is question that forbidden?

Comment: You are assuming that part of the National Guard will start riots or something on Inauguration Day.  Why do you think so?

Comment: Because FBI is already checking them: https://news.sky.com/story/fbi-vets-25-000-national-guard-over-fears-of-insider-attack-at-biden-inauguration-12191193

Comment: Several people who participated in the January 6, 2021 riot were ex-military, ex-police, or currently active police. [At least one person was active in the National Guard.](https://www.armytimes.com/news/your-army/2021/01/14/army-guardsman-first-known-service-member-arrested-after-capitol-riot/) So, yes, it is a concern. The results of these FBI investigations will almost certainly be kept private for some time. Being a Trump supporter is not a crime, and being a Trump supporter does not necessarily mean that one supports insurrection / sedition / treason.

Comment: @user2501323 Just because someone was a Trump supporter, doesn’t mean they’re a traitor. And, for obvious reasons, there’s no good data on how many members of the National Guard are traitors

Comment: On the fence about closing. Information not available to the public is both a reason to close, and as David points out, the answer to this question.

Comment: There are lots of Trump supporters in the military.  The FBI is looking for "extremists."  If the FBI considers a Trump voter an "extremist," as you seem to, then there are a lot of extremists in the military.  If the FBI is interested in actual extremists then they will likely find very few (or none).

Comment: Unless the OP is asserting that elements of the national guard will engage in insurrection or sedition, this question is pointless. Guardsman (an soldiers generally) have varying political opinions; but there is no reason to believe that will lead to them engaging in violence, particularly since the change of power has already occurred. voting to leave closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-election support numbers for Trump in the military at large are somewhat [easier to get](https://www.militarytimes.com/news/pentagon-congress/2020/08/31/as-trumps-popularity-slips-in-latest-military-times-poll-more-troops-say-theyll-vote-for-biden/) and they seemed to be on par with the rest of the population. That doesn't mean all these Trump supporters in the military would support a coup.

[image]

If it's any reasssurance to you in that regard, the armed forces leadership
has [explictly](https://www.usnews.com/news/national-news/articles/2021-01-12/militarys-top-officers-defy-trump-supporters-denounce-violence-in-new-rare-statement) condemned the riots:

> "The violent riot in Washington, D.C. on January 6, 2021 was a direct assault on the U.S. Congress, the Capitol building, and our Constitutional process," wrote the chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staff, Army Gen. Mark Milley, along with the vice chairman and the heads of the Army, Navy, Air Force, Marine Corps, Space Force and National Guard Bureau. "We mourn the deaths of the two Capitol policemen and others connected to these unprecedented events."
>
> "We witnessed actions inside the Capitol Building that were inconsistent with the rule of law. The rights of freedom of speech and assembly do not give anyone the right to resort to violence, sedition and insurrection," they wrote, according to a copy of the memo obtained by U.S. News. "As Service Members, we must embody the values and ideals of the Nation. We support and defend the Constitution. Any act to disrupt the Constitutional process is not only against our traditions, values and oath; it is against the law."

It's somewhat notable that all these making that statement are career military "top brass", i.e. it's not a statement from the (appointed/acting) Secretary of Defense.

Of course, one can't rule out some kind of extremist elements trying to pull off some kind of [Sadat event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Anwar_Sadat#Assassination), but that's why the FBI is investigating.

Comment: A good answer to the question asked.